# how to change the values of table view on UISegment Button click

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have two array and three button in segment control i want that when i load screen by default it get result Array items in table view and then on click on tomorrows button it get nextArray value and show in table

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad{ 
  if(!resultArray){

    resultArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

   [self setUpData];

   if(!nextArray){

    nextArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 }

    [self nextData];
   appointmentsOfDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithArray:resultArray copyItems:YES];
    }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

 return [appointmentsOfDay count];



}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UILabel * dobLabel = nil;
static NSString * Identifier = @"Identifier";
UITableViewCell * cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Identifier] autorelease];

    dobLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 100, 32)];
    dobLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    dobLabel.tag = 999;
    [cell addSubview:dobLabel];
    [dobLabel release];
 }
 else {
     dobLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:999];
 }

appDelegate = (EMRAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

 ObjectData *theCellData = [appointmentOfDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];





     cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
     cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
     cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",theCellData.firstName,theCellData.lasttName];

    dobLabel.text = theCellData.appointmentTime;





      return cell;
    }


  - (void)onDayButtonClick:(id)sender
  {
     UISegmentedControl * segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;


   [appointmentsOfDay removeAllObjects];
    if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {


        [appointmentsOfDay removeAllObjects];


         appointmentsOfDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithArray:resultArray copyItems:YES];



    }

    else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

        [appointmentsOfDay addObject:nextArray];


    }
    else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {

    }

[table reloadData];
}
```

Crash Report

```
 EMR[1161:10703] -[__NSPlaceholderArray arrayWithArray:copyItems:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7320120
2012-04-09 14:13:35.021 EMR[1161:10703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSPlaceholderArray arrayWithArray:copyItems:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7320120'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (0x201d052 0x2d01d0a 0x201eced 0x1f83f00 0x1f83ce2 0xc7a7 0x6bc64e 0x6bc941 0x6ce47d  0x6ce66f 0x6ce93b 0x6cf3df 0x6cf986 0x6cf5a4 0x9660 0x201eec9 0x5f95c2 0x5f955a 0x69eb76 0x69f03f 0x69e2fe 0x61ea30 0x61ec56 0x605384 0x5f8aa9 0x2f72fa9 0x1ff11c5 0x1f56022 0x1f5490a 0x1f53db4 0x1f53ccb 0x2f71879 0x2f7193e 0x5f6a9b 0x25bd 0x2535)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: problem is how may change table data on button click i have data in two arrays NSMutableArrays

Comment: You have written the code for it na??

Comment: yes but i am not getting this done like this

Comment: here reference url for visiting the tutorial for the multiple array fill into UITableview http://bit.ly/I9CSHX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are allocation `appointmentsOfDay` everytime, So remove the following code,

```
 appointmentsOfDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithArray:resultArray copyItems:YES];
```

and add it to viewdidload.

Then,

```
if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        [appointmentsOfDay addObject:resultArray];

    }

else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

        [appointmentsOfDay addObject:nextArray];

    }
```

Comment: it is crashing on arrayWithArray:resultArray copyItems:YES

Comment: yes on viewDidLoad     appointmentsOfDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithArray:resultArray copyItems:YES]; i have written this

Comment: if(!resultArray){
        
  resultArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 }
 
    [self setUpData];
    
    
    if(!nextArray){
        
  nextArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 }

    
    
    [self nextData];
        
    
    appointmentsOfDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithArray:resultArray copyItems:YES];

Comment: check this is in viewDidLoad method

Comment: Can you give the crash report?

Comment: I have also shared crash report

Comment: instead of arrayWithArray use initWithArray

Comment: i have done this it's runing now but when i click tommorow button in segment bar segmentIndex3 then it have 0 value in array when it comes for assigning cell text

Comment: can u help me to do this when i click on segment button it crashes and says unrecognised selector sent

Comment: can you pls give the crash report?

Answer (score 0):

Following code is implementing and may solve your problems

In this i implementing the two array when pressing the button then the another array fill int the Uitable.

In view did load method implement following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.arOne=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e", nil];
    self.arTwo=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"x",@"y",@"z",@"o",@"p", nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method implement following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[(self.btnTapped.selected)?self.arTwo:self.arOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

IBAction method for connection between control and method

```
- (IBAction)btnTitle:(id)sender {
    self.btnTapped.selected=!self.btnTapped.selected;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

May this helping to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that I prefer to use. Have a reference to your segmented control. Declare a read only property

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *appointmentOfDay;
```

and implement it as

```
-(NSArray*) appointmentOfDay {
    NSArray *tData;
    if (self.segmentedControl.value==0) {
        //instantiate tData based on value
    }
    // do for all segmented control value
    return tData;
}
```

And just call `reloadData` when Day button is clicked.